# How to update UILabel text in custom class after initialization (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, storyboard, initialization

I have custom UIStackView class but after initialization I cannot change labels in it, because its referring to different label objects.

```
//  ViewBlocksController.swift
//  player

import UIKit

let nowPlayingControl = NowPlayingController()

@IBDesignable class TitlesFrame: UIStackView {
    //Labels variables
    let songTitle = UILabel()
    let artistAlbumTitle = UILabel()

    //Initialization
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        arrangeView()
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        arrangeView()
    }

    func arrangeView(){
        //Get initial text
        (songTitle.text, artistAlbumTitle.text) = nowPlayingControl.getTitles()

        //Add labels to the stack
        addArrangedSubview(artistAlbumTitle)
        addArrangedSubview(songTitle)

        //Test what label is used
        print(songTitle)
    }

    func updateTitles(){
        (songTitle.text, artistAlbumTitle.text) = nowPlayingControl.getTitles()
    }
}
```

I call updateTitles() from my MainViewController class:

```
//  MainViewController.swift
//  player

import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    let titlesFrame = TitlesFrame()

    //Will call this on custom notification
    func callUpdate(){
        titlesFrame.updateTitles()
    }
}
```

Print gives me following objects:

```
<**UILabel: 0x100c15b90**; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = 'Unknown Artist
\342\200— Unknown ...'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer =
<_UILabelLayer: 0x1700956d0>>

<**UILabel: 0x100d19d90**; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = 'Unknown Artist —
Unknown ...'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer:
0x174097f70>>
```

When I try to update labels with updateTitles() method, it always update 1st object (UILabel: 0x100c15b90). But Storyboard instead displays 2nd object (UILabel: 0x100d19d90) and it is never updated.

How can I update labels on Storyboard?

Comment: Use `IBOutlets` and connect them in storyboard.

Comment: vadian, I do not have this labels on Storyboard. There is only Stack View that inherited from my custom class. I define labels in my class programmatically so I do not have any object to connect IBOutlets.

Comment: you can't assign one property to both of them at once

Comment: you need to break it down into two lines

Comment: `songTitle.text = songTitle`

Comment: `artistAlbumTitle.text = albumName`

Comment: You need to show your getTitles method

Comment: Leo, properties are assigned properly, I have verified that already. My getTitles method returnes tuple `return (songName!, artistAlbum!)`

Comment: With calling `init(frame:)` and `init(coder:)`, you get two different views. Different views cannot share subviews, in other words, your two `TitlesFrame` should not refer the same objects. Why do you need to create two different `TitlesFrame`s in your code?

Comment: OOPer, I do not need 2 views, but this inits seems to be required. Also I assign this class in main ViewController to call updateTitles method from it. Maybe this is the problem? `let titlesFrame = TitlesFrame()` `titlesFrame.updateTitles()`

Comment: Yes, it definitely is the problem. Do you understand that writing `TitlesFrame()` creates new `TitlesFrame` different than the one defined in the storyboard?

Comment: OOPer, I'm fairly new to programming, so I understand the point you said, but not in deep. For me is confusing that override `init(frame: CGRect)` refers to the same object that `titlesFrame.updateTitles()` method, but `required init(coder: NSCoder)` refers to different one. Do you know how I can always refer to the same object?

Comment: It's a very basic part of object oriented programming, and you should have studied it before writing actual code. Even if you call the same initializer, for example `init(coder:)` twice, they return different two instances. You should not write an initializer notation like `TitlesFrame()`, when you do not want to create a new instance. You need to access the instance created with storyboard, not to create another new instance.

Comment: To accomplish this, change the line `let titlesFrame = TitlesFrame()` to `@IBOutlet var titlesFrame:  TitlesFrame!`, and connect it to the UIStackView (`TitlesFrame`) in the `MainViewController`. One more, without using addressing notation like `@OOPer`, stackoverflow does not inform me, so it's very hard to know there's some comments to me.

Comment: @OOPer, thank you! Now it works!

Comment: Happy to hear that you have made it work. Please do not forget to _accept_ your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @OOPer I figured out that my problem was not in the initializers, but in how I refer to my custom class.

To update labels on Storyboard I replaced `let titlesFrame = TitlesFrame()` with `@IBOutlet var titlesFrame: TitlesFrame!` in my MainViewController class. IBOutlet is connected to the inherited UIStackView object on the Storyboard:

```
//  MainViewController.swift
//  player

import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    //IBOutlet is connected to the UIStackView object on the Storyboard
    @IBOutlet weak var titlesFrame: TitlesFrame!

    //Will call this on custom notification
    func callUpdate(){
        titlesFrame.updateTitles()
    }
}
```